# R - return n matches via levenshtein distance

Tags: r, dataframe, tm, levenshtein-distance, stringdist

I would like to find the n best matches to a given string via levenshtein distance.  I know that the `adist` function in R gives the minimal distance, but I am attempting to scale the number of results to, say, 10.  I have some code below.

```
name <- c("holiday inn", "geico", "zgf", "morton phillips")
address <- c("400 lafayette pl tupelo ms", "227 geico plaza chevy chase md", 
     "811 quincy st washington dc", "1911 1st st rockville md")

source1 <- data.frame(name, address)

name <- c("williams sonoma", "mamas bbq", "davis polk", "hop a long diner",
  "joes crag shack", "mike lowry place", "holiday inn", "zummer")

name2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "hi express", "zummer gunsul frasca")
address <- c("2 reads way new castle de", "248 w 4th st newark de",
     "1100 21st st nw washington dc", "1804 w 5th st wilmington de",
     "1208 kenwood parkway holdridge nb", "4203 ocean drive miami fl",
     "400 lafayette pl tupelo ms", "811 quincy st washington dc")
source2 <- data.frame(name, name2, address)

dist.mat.nm <- adist(source1$name, source2$name, partial = T, ignore.case = TRUE)

dist.mat.ad <- adist(source1$address.full, source2$address.full, partial = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
dist.mat <- ifelse(is.na(dist.mat.nm), dist.mat.ad, dist.mat.nm)
dist.mat2 <- ifelse(is.na(dist.mat.ad), dist.mat.nm, dist.mat.ad)
which.match <- function(x, nm) return(nm[which(x == min(x))[1]])
which.index <- function(x, nm) return(which(x == min(x))[1])

source2.matches.name <- apply(dist.mat, 1, which.match, nm = source2$name)
source2.name.index <- apply(dist.mat, 1, which.index, nm = 
source2$names[source2.matches.name])
```

The desired result is a data frame that contains `source1$name`, and columns for the best 5 matches based on lev distance using `adist`, as well as `source1$address` and its best 5 matches.  Perhaps something using `top_n` from `dplyr`?  If anything is unclear let me know.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, the following does what you want.
First I will rerun the code line that creates `dist.mat.ad`, since your code had an error, it refers to columns `address.full` when they are named `address`.

```
dist.mat.ad <- adist(source1$address, source2$address, partial = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

Now the results you want.

```
imat <- apply(dist.mat.nm, 1, order)[1:5, ]
top.nm <- data.frame(name = source1$name)
tmp <- apply(imat, 1, function(i) source2$name[i])
colnames(tmp) <- paste("top", 1:5, sep = ".")
top.nm <- cbind(top.nm, tmp)

imat <- apply(dist.mat.ad, 1, order)[1:5, ]
top.ad <- data.frame(address = source1$address)
tmp <- apply(imat, 1, function(i) source2$address[i])
colnames(tmp) <- paste("top", 1:5, sep = ".")
top.ad <- cbind(top.ad, tmp)
```

The results are in `top.nm` and `top.ad`.
Final clean up.

```
rm(imat, tmp)
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the distances to this?